# Async Checkpointing in Spark Structured Streaming using RocksDB

Tags: pyspark, flink-streaming, spark-structured-streaming, rocksdb, spark-streaming-kafka

I am currently exploring on **enabling async checkpointing in Spark Structured streaming** , but not able to find any way for the same. DataBricks is offering the same for its flavour of Spark.

**Spark Structured Streaming 3.3.1 and RocksDB 7.7.3**

Any suggestions on the same.

Answer (score 0):

Shared your question with the Speedb hive on discord and here is what we have for you; From Hilik, our co-founder and chief scientist:

"Rocksdb currently does not have a mechanism for async checkpoints. The checkpoint is done by halting all the i/o flush the memtables and then use a hard link on the file system. Since this is a very destructive operation it exists on our to-do list. if you are interested  please suggest a feature to the community and we will prioritize it according to the interest"

Hope this helps, let us know if you have any other questions.
Join the discussions on [Discord](https://discord.gg/5fVUUtM2cG) and click [here](https://discord.com/channels/1001437353312796782/1060856326953123852) for the thread about your question